# Discord.py rewrite How to DM commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to have my bot DM the user the help when "-help" is executed.

I have tried doing this in my code already but it will not work.

````
async def help(ctx):
  helpembed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.purple())
  helpembed.set_author(name="Help")
  helpembed.add_field(name="-new", value="Creates a new ticket. [Logged]",inline=False)
  helpembed.add_field(name="-close", value="Closes the ticket.People with the role 'Viewing Team' can close ticets. [Logged]",inline=False)
  helpembed.add_field(name="-setup", value='Sets Up your server so it can be used',inline=False)
  helpembed.add_field(name="-help", value="Shows this message :rofl:",inline=False)
  await client.send_message(ctx.message.author, embed=helpembed)
await ctx.send("Help sent in DM's.")```

The bot should DM the user with help. Instead it does nothing.
````

Answer (score 3):

To send a private message to a user in [discord.py-rewrite](/questions/tagged/discord.py-rewrite), you use the [`User.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.send) method:

```
async def help(ctx):
    ...
    await ctx.author.send(...)
```

This is because `User` is a subclass of the abstract [`Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable) class