# send dm to user by command author on discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I've never used discord.py, this is my first time using it, and I am very confused, I want to make a command so it'll send the help message on DMs, but it does not works, unless you mention yourself.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.command()
async def help(ctx, user:discord.Member, *, message=None):
    message = 'test'
    embed = discord.Embed(title=message)
    await user.send(embed=embed)
```

So, if you do $help, it'll do nothing, but if u do $help @John Doe#0001 it'll DM John Doe or anyone you mention.
I am sorry if this sounds stupid..

Comment: Please [read the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the bot to message you, the person who invoked the command, you shouldn't pass the user argument. However, if you still want to mention someone so you can send them your help message, you can make `user=None`, an [optional argument](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-optional-arguments/#:%7E:text=A%20Python%20optional%20argument%20is%20an%20argument%20with%20a%20default,if%20one%20is%20not%20specified.), within the function itself.

Do note that in the code snippet I have provided I made `message` not an argument, but something already in the function. Do view the revised code below.

```py
@client.command()
async def help(ctx, user:discord.Member=None):
    if user == None: # if no user is passed..
        user = ctx.author # ..make the command author the user
    message = "test"
    embed = discord.Embed(title=message)
    await user.send(embed=embed)
```

**Helpful Questions**:

- [How to send a Private Message to the message author?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55944645/14420546) - SO
- [How to DM commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55895117/discord-py-rewrite-how-to-dm-commands) - SO
- [`ctx`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) - Discord.py Docs

Comment: Thanks! I'am really new to discord.py so I didn't know all that! It really helped man.

Comment: @Wikileas If this helped you, do press the tick underneath this answer's up and down votes to close your question, thanks! Do the same if a different answer helped you better than this one

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean sending a help message to the person who used the command but didn't to mention the user?

Here's how:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    message = 'test'
    embed = discord.Embed(title=message)
    await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
```

Use `ctx.author.send` to send a message to user used the command

Comment: Thanks! I'am really new to discord.py so I didn't know all that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the help gui to be sent in dms , if u want to send the help prompt in the **command's channel as well as dms** add `await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)`

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
   embed = discord.Embed(color=0xFFFFFF)
   embed.set_author(name='HELP MESSAGE' icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
   embed.add_field(name="help" , value='sends the help message in dms')
   await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
```

You can add ur custom embed instead of the embed in the above code .. Hope you understood .

Answer (score -2):

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx, user:discord.Member, *, message=None):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{message}", description=f"Sent by {ctx.author}")
    await user.send(embed=embed)
```

I would try something like this.